# how to add sound effects to a Groovy / SwingBuilder application?

Tags: groovy, audio

I've created a desktop application using Groovy and SwingBuilder.
I would like to add sound effects to my app.
How can I do that ?

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing specific in groovy that you could use to add sound effect. Instead just use the existing Java libraries like this:

```
import  sun.audio.*;
import  java.io.*;

AudioStream as = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream(Filename));         
AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
```

Encapsulate this code in a separate class and call it from your groovy application.